# Finding all solutions of an exponential equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, roots

> Find the product of all the solutions of $\displaystyle\left(\frac{x^2-5x}{6}\right)^{x^2-2}=1$ times the number of solutions.

I don't know how to solve an exponential equation, so I've done as follow:

1. If you raise something to the $0$th power you get $1$, so:
       $$\begin{align*}
           &x^2 - 2 = 0\\
           &(x+\sqrt{2})(x-\sqrt{2}) = 0\\
           &x = \pm \sqrt{2}
           \end{align*}$$
2. If the result is $1$ then $\displaystyle\frac{x^2-5x}{6}=\pm1$. When it is equal to $1$ the exponent can be anything, if it is $-1$ it must be even. So:

   - $x^2-5x-6=0 \Rightarrow x_1 = -1, x_2 = 6$
   - $x^2 - 5x + 6 = 0$, $x_1 = 2 \Rightarrow x_2 = 3$ but $x=3$ is not acceptable because $x^2-2 = 7$, odd.

So the solutions are: $S=\{-\sqrt{2}, -1, 2, \sqrt{2}, 6\}$, and the answer to the problem $120$.

Is my work correct? Are there any other methods (simpler, complicated ones)?

**EDIT:** Wolfram|Alpha does not agree with me:
[Wolfram|Alpha results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?_=1321374428234&i=%28%28x%2a%2a2%20-%205x%29%20/%206%29%20%2a%2a%20%28x%2a%2a2%20-%202%29%20=%201&fp=1&incTime=true)

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you. Why WolframAlpha does not give all the solutions?

Comment: I just plotted the function, and it looks like those are the only answers, assuming, of course, that $x$ is real.

Comment: @Phonon: Oh yes I forgot it: $x$ is real!

Comment: Your approach is the one that I’d use.

Comment: @rubik How is the function defined near $\sqrt 2$? And how should a numerical algorithm find the solutions if the function is not even defined nearby?

Comment: It's fairly standard in elementary algebra and precalculus to restrict the base (whether constant or variable) of an exponentiation to be positive when the exponent is variable. I suspect this convention is behind the Wolfram|Alpha results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve such an equation is taking the logarithm. You will get

$$(x^2-2)\log\left(\left|\frac{x^2-5}{6}\right|\right)=0$$

and the absolute value is needed to avoid the logarithm will take complex values. Then one has to solve

$$x^2-2=0$$

and

$$\frac{x^2-5}{6}=\pm 1.$$

This will provide the full set of solutions.

Comment: Thank you, but I haven't studied logarithms yet, so I have some difficulties to understand the step you made (a logarithms property, I guess). Thank you anyway!

Comment: Hi rubik. As you will learn later: this is only valid thanks to the logarithm being an invertible function. It is important to recognize when one uses invertible and non-invertible functions when solving equations, since one may lose solutions or introduce false ones if the function applied is not invertible.

Comment: Great method for solving this problem, you deserve more credit for your intuitive thinking.  However, since the question asks to **find all solutions**, I think it is appropriate to extend the logarithm to complex numbers.  I also think that the absolute values shouldn't be there because there is no step that called for their need.  Instead, you could simply say that the $\log$ of a negative number is something, but when multiplied by $0$, it no longer matters.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the function $a^x$ is defined only when $a>0$. So firstly you should write 
$\frac{x^2-5x}{6}\ge0$, so $x\in(-\infty;0)\cup(5;\infty)$. That is why from the solutions you got remain only $x_1=-1$, $x_2=-\sqrt{2}$ and also $x_3=6$. So the set of solutions is $\{-\sqrt2, -1, 6\}$ and the answer to your problem is $18\sqrt2$.

Comment: With $x=2$ you get $(-1)^2=1$ which looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Anyway you have a function of type $a^x$ whose domain is $a>0$.

Comment: @Tigran Hakobyan, your reason about a>0 is just why Alpha Wolfram derived only 3 points. But there is a bit difference between equation and function, which I mean $a^n$ still makes sense for a<0, where n is an integer, as Henry just mentioned. However, rubik need to check if LHS makes sense when x equals to some real number.

Comment: @puresky, the equation is given by the function of type $a^x$ which means that we should have $a>0$. In fact, Wolfram Alpha missed the solution $x=6$. Otherwise we could write:

$-\sqrt[3](2)=(-2)^{\frac{1}{3}}=(-2)^{\frac{2}{6}}=(4)^{\frac{1}{6}}=\sqrt[6]{4}=\sqrt[3]{2}$, which of course is wrong.

Comment: @TigranHakobyan, it seems that you didn't notice I had mentioned that n must be an integer for $a^n$, or a rational if you want to consider complex numbers, when $a<0$. And also I don't think that we need to treat $a^x$ as a function just because there is an x. Dave L. Renfro also didn't say x should be variable. Besides, considering complex, $\sqrt[3]{1}$ is subset of $\sqrt[6]{1}$.